# Transposing data to a new worksheet with two column criteria

Tags: excel, vba

So this problem has been presented to me and it's becoming a huge roadblock in the production of my website. I'm not new to excel when it comes to the interface but writing functions is something that I have never had to deal with. I have a table with values labeled by reference number that basically relay a form that was filled out by a certain provider. The column with all the different answers to the fields (Yes, it has different field answers in one column, sigh) needs to be broken up so I can label them with column headers in order to eventually import them into an SQL database. The source is current delivered in this format:

[image: Source data]

What I need to do is be able to fill out a column-based version of these values that looks like:

[image: Expected Aggregate Results]

The criteria for creating columns is based on the values in A (ref #) B C and D. I'm guessing I need to create some sort of conditional statement that checks if C and D are equal to a certain value (C and D designate the type of information that is in E so they are pretty much my key element/conditionals) and then places the information in cell E underneath the correct column header. I have been researching functions such as VLookup/Match/Index and I can't make much sense of how to apply them or if there is possibly a better function I can use to accomplish my task. Even a reference to a relevant SO thread would be great at this point. I basically just need some guidance as to what it would take to make this work. On top of that, the reference numbers ascend but are not in any particular order therefore I am wondering if it possible to feed a function a list of reference numbers to increment to once all the conditionals have all been run through for a particular reference number.

EDIT: Ok so here is my new issue -->

The images as you requested
Original Data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6rzj.jpg
After VBA Script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3q9.jpg

This is the only code we edited:

```
vHDRs = Array(Array("Reference #", -1, -2), _
                  Array("Provider Name", 300, 100), _
                  Array("Provider Number", 300, 300), _
                  Array("County", 200, 400), _
                  Array("Address", 100, 100), _
                  Array("Zip", 200, 300))
```

As you can see, the column for addresses does not populate

Comment: Where is the phone number coming from?

Comment: line 616659 in the original image. It's not real it's just for the example but yea.

Comment: Column C has a value of 4300 and column D has a value of 100 which designates phone number on the form.

Comment: A few array formulas should do this nicely but the calculation load would be logarithmically increased according to the total number of rows. It would be fine for <1K rows, acceptable up to 5K rows and anything above that would pretty much throw your computer into conniptions. VBA would seem to be the best solution for large data sets.

Comment: There are 23 million entries in our biggest table and this particular table has 130,000 entries. So yea, our attempts tonight have done exactly that. Do you know any good resources for VBA that might help?

Comment: I've heard [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is a good online resource. When you search for examples, the keyword you are looking for is *transpose*. I've written several myself. TBBH, I wouldn't mind taking a run at this; should be no more than a half-page of code but I've already typed out sample data from three other questions today that failed to provide anything short of an image of the source data.

Comment: I tried a transpose function earlier that wasn't successful as some of these forms have a different amount of answers in column E, therefore no macro can accurately know how many lines to transpose as it will throw the entire table off.

Comment: *Transpose* can be used to describe a function but it also means to take data organized vertically and reorganize it horizontally. *Pivot* may be another good term that describes your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll use those two terms in my searches. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly standard VBA sub with enough safeties that it shouldn't destroy anything of substance.

```
Sub My_Organize()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vHDRs As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iREFNO As Long, iREFROW As Long, iLR As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, app As Application

    Set app = Application
    app.ScreenUpdating = False
    app.EnableEvents = False
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    app.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Organized").Delete
    On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Organized"
    Set ws = Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    vHDRs = Array(Array("Reference #", -1, -2), _
                  Array("Provider Name", 4200, 100), _
                  Array("Phone #", 4300, 100))

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vHDRs) + 1) = app.Transpose(app.Index(vHDRs, , 1))

    With Sheet1
        iLR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(3), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Key3:=.Columns(4), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

            For rw = 2 To iLR
                If iREFNO <> .Cells(rw, 1).Value2 Then
                    iREFNO = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    iREFROW = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws.Cells(iREFROW, 1) = iREFNO
                End If
                For i = LBound(vHDRs, 1) To UBound(vHDRs, 1)
                    If .Cells(rw, 3).Value2 = vHDRs(i)(1) And _
                       .Cells(rw, 4).Value2 = vHDRs(i)(2) Then
                          ws.Cells(iREFROW, i + 1) = .Cells(rw, 5).Value2
                          Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
            Next rw
        End With
    End With

Safe_Exit:
    Set ws = Nothing
    app.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    app.DisplayAlerts = True
    app.EnableEvents = True
    app.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Edit the nested array of `vHDRs` information to match what you want to collect and transpose from the source worksheet. Just add a new nested array into that and change the label and the numbers to match from columns C & D. They do not have to be in any special order in the outer array but each inner array should be *label, column C, column D*.

With your data pasted into a new workbook's *Sheet1*, run that routine against it. It will create a new worksheet at the end of the queue and transpose the data according to the parameters you set up in the array of column header labels, and two other numbers to match from columns C and D on the source worksheet (i.e. *Sheet1*).

If you run that repeatedly against 23M rows (in multiple worksheets) then the values could be bulk fed into an array so that all processing would be done in memory.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing and worked. Thank you so much. I apologize for not responding last night, did not realize you were going to do this for me xD. I am trying to upvote/mark as correct but don't seem to have enough reputation.

Comment: @Habitat - Glad to hear that worked out for you. Any chance you could provide some rough figures on execution efficiency? (e.g. rows in source, columns to transpose, CPU(s) of host machine and time elapsed). Not a big deal but I like to keep track of how my methods work in different scenarios whenever possible.

Comment: I won't be able to contact my co-worker who implemented it until tomorrow but I can send you that information asap

Comment: Edit: I tried it myself but where can I get the runtime information? It seems to work almost instantly for the 130,000 row table

Comment: @Habitat - No worries then. I was more concerned with 1 minute vs 1 hour than 1.5 seconds vs. 3.5 seconds. If it is running as well as you have experienced and producing results correctly then I have accomplished what I set out to do. Good luck with your work!

Comment: It's definitely only a few seconds if more than 1 at all (Like I said it's almost instant in any table I've attempted). I will definitely let you know how the 23 million table goes...One question though: Is there a way I can apply this script outside of excel as we have been opening our 23 million row table in Delimit because obviously excel has a 1 million row limit.

Comment: @Habitat - Any experienced programmer should be able to transcribe that code into any language you prefer. If you want to tackle this yourself but are unsure on a language, you might want to look at [PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) to generate a scripted routine that could be automated every day.

Comment: Thanks I'll check out powershell. I am a PHP/HTML/Jquery guy who is also well-versed in regular java...not sure of how to implement into java but I'm sure google is my friend here. Thank you for all your help! You've done much more than I asked of you and you literally saved the day xD.

Comment: Hey @Jeeped one more question my co-worker said when he adds more columns to the array it creates a column header but will not copy the data over. What are we doing wrong? We have 
`vHDRs = Array(Array("Reference #", -1, -2), _ 
Array("Provider Name", 300, 100), _ 
Array("Zip Code", 200, 100), _ 
Array("Address", 100, 100), _ 
Array("State", 200, 200))`

Iike I said it creates address and state headers but does not add the data. What do I need to do to the code elsewhere to add more fields? There are more fields than included above

Comment: Scratch that, the issue lies solely in the address field. Could it be the data type? its the only field with both letters and numbers.

Comment: @Habitat - I would really have to see some data that is causing the error in order make any determination as to an appropriate modification to the code. Edit your question to include some 3-5 full records of redacted sample data (a couple that work and a couple that don't) and I will see if I can locate the problem and fix it. Is there another line that matches 100, 100? I did not take column B into account as your sample data did not require it.

Comment: i edited the original post, but let me check to make sure that there isn't another 100, 100

Edit: Yep it's the only one with 100,100

Comment: hey man I really apologize I sent you on a wild goose chase. We had used Delimit to extract all values that had S200001 in column b previously and that had corrupted our file. In the original file the addresses extract perfectly. The only problem is we need to to use column B as a search criteria also. Is it difficult to amend the code for this? Ty again.

Comment: if you get a chance today would love to discuss the script, if maybe you could explain how some of it actually works I may be able to modify myself? Thanks again

Comment: a) I've cut out some over-reaching safety checks that were discarding the first line of a new match. In your case, this happened to be the *Address* field. Should be good to go now. b) Your sample data still shows no reason to incorporate column B. c) Generic module code is offered freely. If you need me to explain it to you then that would be time-and-a-half plus the inverse of the instruction level. ;)

Comment: Haha I was actually going to say that I would be willing to possibly paypal you. I wish SO had a PM feature. Anyways thank you so much for this you have no idea how much you saved more than just my ass today xD. Edit: Just tried it works like a charm. Much <3